# Is there a way to disable all write access for a specific user in a directory?

Tags: permissions, acl, access-control

I recently learned about ACL and `setfacl` for setting per-user access rights. But there is one thing that I cannot figure out how to pull off, and that is restricting all write(*) access for a specific user in a specific directory *and everything inside it*.

To put it another way, consider a user `some_user` and a directory `some_dir` (suppose `chmod 777 some_dir` has been used).
Is there a way to restrict `some_user`'s write access - **without** altering any other access right - in `some_dir` and all of its content?

What I have tried/thought of:

- `setfacl -R -m u:some_user:rx some_dir/` won't do the trick as it would give `some_user` read access to files that the user might have not been able to read before, as well as execute access to files the user might have not been able to execute before.
- Setting a `r-x` mask to `some_dir` recursively (again with `setfacl`) also won't do it, as there is no way to make a mask specific to one user (as far as I know)

Having skimmed through ACL documentation, I haven't come across anything that points to this direction, so just to be clear, I am not necessarily looking for a way to do this with ACL.

*(*) or read, or execute access - I guess it shouldn't matter which one it is, but I will stick with write access to keep it simple*

Answer (score 0):

Before applying acl for user p3 Now every have full access on directory k2

```
 mkdir k2

 chmod 777 k2
getfacl k2
# file: k2
# owner: praveen
# group: praveen
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
```

Now lets restrict user p3 write acess on the directory k2

```
 setfacl -m u:p3:rx k2
$ getfacl k2
# file: k2
# owner: praveen
# group: praveen
user::rwx
user:p3:r-x    =====> user p3  have only read and execute acess not write
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::rwx
```

Comment: I see what you are talking about, but as I mention in the first example I give, if this was to be applied recursively, it would cause non-readable/non-executable directories and files to become both readable and executable. Right?